# Is it safe to put two hard disk in one case?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I want to put two hard disk in one case (cover). One hard disk is on the top of another and there is no gap or there is nothing between it. As shown in the attached photo.

[image: .]

Is it safe to do so? Does magnetic field or magnets of hard disk can cause any problem with hard disk if I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without problems if you don't operate them.

I doubt you are thinking of using them while in the bag, and just are looking for a method to carry them.

Harddisks are shielded enough for their internal magnets to have any influence on adjacent devices, but when they operate, they do generate heat. It is this heat you would be concerned about.

Comment: Yes I only want to put it to only carry them around. I'll remove the case whenever I want to use the disk.

Comment: Yes, then that'll work. Feel free to accept my answer so others know you don't seek further help.